# Error with Box SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, box-api

I am developing an Android App (using Android Studio) which uses the Box SDK.I have successfully imported the Box Java and Android modules but when I run the application, i get the following errors in the console:

...while parsing com/box/boxjavalibv2/BoxClient$1.class
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\android-sdks\build-tools\20.0.0\dx.bat --dex --output F:\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\boxjavalibv2-3.0.12-e9104d1595867bda1af43e541b58e14f23fb2b9a.jar F:\workspace\BoxJavaLibraryV2\build\libs\boxjavalibv2-3.0.12.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
>       ...while parsing com/box/boxjavalibv2/BoxClient$1.class
>       1 error; aborting

I have tried changing from Java7 to default,but of no help.

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong java compiler nevertheless. Maybe your default is Java 8?

Comment: is there any way i can get my code to work without reverting to 1.7?

Comment: I'm sorry, no there isn't. If you use any Java 8 feature you have to refactor that part to good old java 1.7

Comment: So just changing it using "compileOption" in gradle would do?

Comment: Maybe. I would use a real Java 7 compiler and not only the compatibility mode. And of course, don't use any Java 8 features.

Comment: Thanks.Reverting to Java7 worked.

Comment: getting a new error though.Check the below link,may be you can help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661654/box-sdk-multiple-dex-error

Comment: Looks like they're remaining files from the previous builds. try to clean the project, if that doesn't work, delete the content of gradles build directories.